# want to call a procedure multiple times and send values from a query as arguments

Tags: sql-server

Guys I want to call a procedure multiple times with ouput of multiple row values as argument to a procedure.My query is like this:

```
select RoomID from tbWalkInRooms where WID =@ID
```

now this query is returning multiple roomid's and I have to send one differnt roomid as argument to a procedure each time.

Comment: use cursor to loop through results

Comment: why not combine them into one sproc and use an inner join for the 2 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understand your question, you can achieve that by ysing cursor:

```
declare @room_id int

declare room_id_cursor cursor for select RoomID from tbWalkInRooms where WID =@ID
open room_id_cursor
fetch next from room_id_cursor into @room_id
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  exec your_procedure @room_id
  fetch next from room_id_cursor into @room_id
end
close room_id_cursor
deallocate room_id_cursor
```